# Is there a way to tell if an alien is aggressive or friendly on Starbound?

Tags: starbound

I have found that some aliens cause me no harm at all, whereas others will try and kill me.  Is there a way of knowing for sure if an alien is going to kill me or not before I go stabbing it?

I'd rather not go killing 20 peaceful creatures if they were never going to harm me in the first place!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't tell if an alien is aggressive just by looking at them, but there is an audio cue you can use: hostile aliens will face you and roar/growl/squeak/whatever-their-sound-is before they start their attack.  While passive aliens also make noises, your presence isn't the trigger and more often than not they will remain silent as you approach.  If you aren't sure about an alien's disposition then cautiously move toward it and listen to its reaction.

Comment: Given how fast do most hostiles run, this isn't very safe method.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to tell whether a creature is hostile or not is to walk near them. On a new planet when you discover a creature you don't know yet, walk up to them slowly. If they don't attack you by the time you're almost close enough to smack them with your sword, they're friendly.